# Importing Robot Libraries in RED has issue which shows in red(not imported)

Tags: robotframework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgviI.png)When I add the project and in RED eclipse when i do add robot nature it does not shows me error pop up.
Just the libraries are in red (not imported).

My screen shot will help.

Same happens for the robot framework referenced libraries as well.

Every time i have to rebuild them it changed from the red colour.

Answer (score 0):

try to clean and check the path of the files inside the Python_Version folder